# Steps involved in classifying images?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, machine-learning, classification

I am very new to machine learning and have been implementing ML algorithms on the datasets.
But how do I go about classifying images using the Ml algorithms?

How do I  feed the images to the learning models in the form of numpy arrays?

Can anyone brief me about the steps involved? I have been reading about feature extraction but I am not able to figure out how to do that.

Comment: This is not the right place to ask, since you don't have any code. You can try with cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Image classification is not much different, at its core, from any other sort of classification.

Your data are images, right? Well, we need to create some variables ("features") from those images in order to get a sense of what's in the images. Computers can understand matrices, not just straight-up images like humans do (although there are arguments that what humans are doing when they see images is deconstructing images into patterns of pixels, but let's keep it simple). Using OpenCV is a great way to turn image pixels into matrices.

Each matrix (i.e. each image) will have a corresponding tag or classification (e.g. "dog" or "cat"). You feed those matrices through your algorithm in order to classify each image.

That will get you started. There's so much that goes into machine learning related to images, but at its core, the problem is the same as elsewhere: take a matrix/set of data and use an algorithm to find patterns in the data and a function that maps the input to the output label. You might be served well by reading an intro to machine learning book or taking a course.